# Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Contains

Tags: jquery

So I'm using:

```
    jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a, i, m) { 
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0; 
};

function detectResults() {

    if ($("#clientList:visible").length == 0) {
        $("#clientList").hide();
        $("#noRecords").show();
    } else {
        $("#noRecords").hide();
    }
}
//End Search Clients Result Detection
$("document").ready(function() {
        //Search Clients 
    $("#searchClients").keyup(function(e) {

        var query = $("#searchClients").val();

        $("#clientList div").hide(1, function() {
            $("span.firstname:Contains('"+query+"')").parent().show();
            console.log('Show Results');
        });

        setTimeout("detectResults()", 100);
        console.log('Search Keyup');

        return false;

    });
    //End Search Clients
    });
```

But everytime I keyup in the searchClients bar I get an uncaught syntax error.  Anyone know what this might be?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: why don't you try using `extends`.

Comment: I think `:contains()` is included in jQuery.

Comment: @Blender If it's included in jQuery I can just remove what I did up top?  Cuz I tried that, but it still presents the same problem.

Comment: @DanielA.White I've never used extends

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @Pekka 1.6.4 hosted by Google.

Comment: Okay. Odd. `contains()` should be available there. But why are you defining contains specifically? Can you try removing the first trhee lines?

Comment: @Pekka I did remove them.  After I realized contains() was already there.  But even after I remove those lines I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you try lowercase `contains()`?

Comment: @Pekka wow... haha Thank.  Everything works great now.

Comment: @Pekka Know how I can make it ignore uppercase and lowercase?  Because if I put in "b" it works, but "B" does not produce the results with "b"

Comment: @Ani oh! Interesting. No, I don't know how to do that. To be honest, I assumed it is case insensitive

Comment: @Pekka I'll have to figure it out.  Thanks for answering the question at hand though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lowercase `:contains()`.